# Taxonomy do Advanced Custom Fields não sendo exibida!

Tags: wordpress

Boa noite pessoa, primeira vez participando aqui.
Criei um tema em WordPress mas estou com um problema que está tomando meu dia. Eu não sou programador, mas sei criar temas para wordPress pois entendo a lógica do PHP.
Seguinte:
Tenho a Caminhões que exibe os produtos da categoria Caminhões, e tenho a outra que exibe os produtos da categoria Tratores.
Como vocês vêem a página Caminhões exibe o arquivo archive-caminhoes.php mostrando a lista de produtos que cadastrei com a categoria caminhões, já a página Tratores não faz o mesmo sendo que estou usando a mesma lógica com o archive-tratores.php
Alguém poderia ajudar?

```
add_action('init', 'produtos_registrer');
  function produtos_registrer(){
    $labels = array(
      'name' => _x('Produtos', 'post type general name'),
      'singular_name' => _x('produtos', 'post type singular name'),
      'add_new' => _x('Adicionar Produtos', 'Produtos'),
      'add_new_item' => __('Adicionar Produtos'),
      'edit_item' => __('Editar Produtos'),
      'new_item' => __('Novas Produtos'),
      'view_item' => __('Ver Produtos'),
      'search_items' => __('Procurar Produtos'),
      'not_found' =>  __('Nada encontrado'),
      'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nada encontrado no lixo'),
      'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );
    $args = array(
      'labels' => $labels,
      'public' => true,
      'publicly_queryable' => true,
      'show_ui' => true,
      'query_var' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-tools',
      'capability_type' => 'post',
      'hierarchical' => false,
      'supports'    => array( 'title','category','taxonomy','editor','excerpt','thumbnail','gallery'),
      'rewrite' => true,
      'menu_position' => 5
    );
    register_post_type('produtos',$args);
  }

  register_taxonomy(
    "categorias", "produtos",
    array(
      "label" => "Categoria dos produtos",
      "singular_label" => "Categoria do produto",
      "rewrite" => true,
      "hierarchical" => true
    )
  );
```

Aqui o archive-caminhoes.php:

```
<div class="lastest">

            <?php
            $args = array('post_type'=>'produtos', 'taxonomy'=>'categorias', 'term'=>'caminhoes', 'numberposts' => -1, 'order' => 'DESC' );
            $projetos = get_posts( $args );
            if( $projetos ):
                ?>

                <?php
                foreach( $projetos as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
                ?>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <article class="box-produtos">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="circle">
                                    <?php
                                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                        the_post_thumbnail();
                                    } ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <header>
                                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                </header>
                                <p>
                                    <em>Cód.:</em> <?php the_field('codigo_do_produto'); ?>
                                    <br>
                                    <em>Linha:</em> <?php the_field('linha_do_produto'); ?>
                                </p>
                                <footer>
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-default" title="">Ver produto</a>
                                </footer>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>


            <?php endforeach; ?>

Aqui o archive-tratores.php:

<div class="lastest">

                <?php
                $args = array('post_type'=>'produtos', 'taxonomy'=>'categorias', 'term'=>'tratores', 'numberposts' => -1, 'order' => 'DESC' );
                $projetos = get_posts( $args );
                if( $projetos ):
                    ?>

                    <?php
                    foreach( $projetos as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
                    ?>

                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <article class="box-produtos">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="circle">
                                        <?php
                                        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                            the_post_thumbnail();
                                        } ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <header>
                                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                    </header>
                                    <p>
                                        <em>Cód.:</em> <?php the_field('codigo_do_produto'); ?>
                                        <br>
                                        <em>Linha:</em> <?php the_field('linha_do_produto'); ?>
                                    </p>
                                    <footer>
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-default" title="">Ver produto</a>
                                    </footer>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    </div>


                <?php endforeach; ?>
<div>


Eu criei no plugin advanced custom fields os campos chamando o tipo de post produtos que é o nome lá no functions, creio que algo ta limitando pra mostrar apenas uma taxonomia (categoria), pois quando coloca na url http://cosmosmetalurgica.com.br/produtos/ mostra todos e os que são da categoria Tratores estão genéricos, por isso a single não mostra o botão de voltar pra ver todos os produtos. Sem contar que a página Tratores está chamando a page.php e não o archive-tratores.php que nem o caminhões
Tags
Envie-me novas respostas a minhas publicações por e-mail (configurações)
```

Aqui o archive-tratores.php:

```
<div class="lastest">

                <?php
                $args = array('post_type'=>'produtos', 'taxonomy'=>'categorias', 'term'=>'tratores', 'numberposts' => -1, 'order' => 'DESC' );
                $projetos = get_posts( $args );
                if( $projetos ):
                    ?>

                    <?php
                    foreach( $projetos as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
                    ?>

                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <article class="box-produtos">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="circle">
                                        <?php
                                        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                            the_post_thumbnail();
                                        } ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <header>
                                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                    </header>
                                    <p>
                                        <em>Cód.:</em> <?php the_field('codigo_do_produto'); ?>
                                        <br>
                                        <em>Linha:</em> <?php the_field('linha_do_produto'); ?>
                                    </p>
                                    <footer>
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-default" title="">Ver produto</a>
                                    </footer>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    </div>


                <?php endforeach; ?>
<div>
```

Eu criei no plugin advanced custom fields os campos chamando o tipo de post produtos que é o nome lá no functions, creio que algo ta limitando pra mostrar apenas uma taxonomia (categoria), pois quando coloca na url /produtos/ mostra todos e os que são da categoria Tratores estão genéricos, por isso a single não mostra o botão de voltar pra ver todos os produtos. Sem contar que a página Tratores está chamando a page.php e não o archive-tratores.php que nem o caminhões

---

Na parte de caminhões por exemplo eu estou chamando pelo termo, mas agora ele mostra separado mas mostra todos os produtos em ambas categorias. E qual single que eu chamo? single-tratores.php, single-caminhoes.php ou uso outro nome?

```html
                <?php
                $args = array('post_type'=>'produtos', 'taxonomy'=>'categorias', 'term'=>'tratores', 'numberposts' => -1, 'order' => 'DESC' );
                $projetos = get_posts( $args );
                if( $projetos ):
                    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você deu os nomes errados pros arquivos. Guarde o link da [Hierarquia de Templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png) e consulte sempre que precisar.

No seu caso você criou uma taxonomia `categorias`, associado ao tipo `produtos`, então imagino que `tratores` e `caminhões` são termos dessa taxonomia.

Experimente renomear `archive-tratores.php` para `taxonomy-categorias-tratores.php` e `archive-caminhoes.php` para `taxonomy-categorias-caminhoes.php`.

Como muitos templates são parecidos é fácil confundir qual está sendo usado. Para conferir qual template está sendo chamado em cada página você pode colocar esse trecho no `functions.php`:

```
/** 
 * Exibe qual template foi escolhido para exibir a página
 * TODO: retirar esse trecho antes de colocar o site no ar
 */ 
add_filter( 'template_include', function( $template ) {
    error_log( 'template utilizado: '.$template ); // para ver no log do php
    var_dump( 'template utilizado: '.$template ); // para imprimir na tela
    // ex.: template utilizado: '/srv/www/site/htdocs/wp-content/themes/tema/archive.php'
    return $template;
}, 9999 );
```

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo, não tenho muito conhecimento com essa parte, simplesmente resolvi tentar, nunca tinha tentando antes, eu fazia tudo via post e categorias para cadastrar produtos, projetos, carros etc, ai quando tinha blog eu me quebrava kkk. Vou tentar e te dou um retorno!

Comment: Consegui resolver a questão no single.php